# How to remove file while restoring tar incremental backup when the file is deleted from source

Tags: backup, tar

I am using Linux tar command to take a full backup of one of my application data directory on every Monday and then later incremental backup on other days.

Everything is all right but my problem is that if any of the files have been deleted from the source, those files are still available when I restore the data from the backup.

How can I make sure that the file is deleted when I am restoring the files from the backup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question and I thought of sharing with all.

During the restoration of files, make sure that the following switch is passed.

```
 --listed-incremental=/dev/null
```